# stuck on trying to code a "digital aux switch"

Tags: python, pygame

I'm trying to make a code that works like an aux switch like the photo below shows[image]

i have seen nobody trying to do this so far. closest ive seen is someone trying to play mp3s which got me here:

```
from pygame import mixer #Playing sound
mixer.init(devicename="CABLE Input (VB-Audio Virtual Cable)") #Initialize it with the correct device
mixer.music.load('./we dont talk anymore.mp3')
mixer.music.play()
```

This code will take an mp3 and play it to a specific output

i know how to switch the two audio inputs i just need to know how to get audio inputs pushed to that output.
(for people who dont know: Im using virtual audio cable. this lets me use an output as an input device (the code above works if you want to play music to an output device )so i have to push my input to a specific output

Comment: so far my knowledge on this is. 1. I need to playback my audio to an output device 2. the output device I need to output it too will not be my "default output device" 3. i need to be able to use pygame for controller buttons because im going to use an xbox controller to switch the two inputs

Answer (score 0):

```
import argparse

import sounddevice as sd
import numpy  # Make sure NumPy is loaded before it is used in the callback
assert numpy  # avoid "imported but unused" message (W0611)


def int_or_str(text):
    """Helper function for argument parsing."""
    try:
        return int(text)
    except ValueError:
        return text


parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(add_help=False)
parser.add_argument(
    '-l', '--list-devices', action='store_true',
    help='show list of audio devices and exit')
args, remaining = parser.parse_known_args()
if args.list_devices:
    print(sd.query_devices())
    parser.exit(0)
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
    description=__doc__,
    formatter_class=argparse.RawDescriptionHelpFormatter,
    parents=[parser])
parser.add_argument(
    '-i', '--input-device', type=int_or_str,
    help='input device (numeric ID or substring)')
parser.add_argument(
    '-o', '--output-device', type=int_or_str,
    help='output device (numeric ID or substring)')
parser.add_argument(
    '-c', '--channels', type=int, default=2,
    help='number of channels')
parser.add_argument('--dtype', help='audio data type')
parser.add_argument('--samplerate', type=float, help='sampling rate')
parser.add_argument('--blocksize', type=int, help='block size')
parser.add_argument('--latency', type=float, help='latency in seconds')
args = parser.parse_args(remaining)


def callback(indata, outdata, frames, time, status):
    if status:
        print(status)
    outdata[:] = indata


try:
    with sd.Stream(device=(args.input_device, args.output_device),
                   samplerate=args.samplerate, blocksize=args.blocksize,
                   dtype=args.dtype, latency=args.latency,
                   channels=args.channels, callback=callback):
        print('#' * 80)
        print('press Return to quit')
        print('#' * 80)
        input()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    parser.exit('')
except Exception as e:
    parser.exit(type(e).__name__ + ': ' + str(e))
```